# Xcode Release configuration behaves different

Tags: objective-c, configuration, debugging, release

I'm making a iPhone App written in Objective-C using the Cocos2d game engine.

I'm using Xcode v3.2.1 with the 3.1.2 iOS. At this point I have always ran my project under Debug Configuration. When I set it to release configuration certain elements of my game are no longer behaving correctly.

My logic that worked in the debug configuration doesn't work in release configuration. What makes release configuration behave differently and what about release configuration would cause problems in the code. This holds true on both the simulator and an actual device.

I'm thinking it may be something within one of my loops, but I'm not sure. Is there guidelines that should be followed under release configuration that are different then debug configuration?

I also ran a Build and Analyse thinking perhaps I was doing something I shouldn't but it came up clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differences between release and debug builds are often caused by uninitialized variables.

Comment: Thanks, It was a compounding problem... first the Analyzer didn't seem to find a uninitialized boolean I had (thanks for the tip for future reference) and upon solving that I forgot to clean all targets before I ran again. So regardless of the changes I made I still had the problem.